# Fourier Transform of temperature Green Function

Tags: temperature, fourier-transform, greens-functions, wick-rotation

I am doing a calculation involving a temperature Green function for some operator $\hat{A}$:
$$G_{\hat{A}}(\tau)=-\Big\langle{T_\tau\big(\hat{A}(\tau)\hat{A}^\dagger \big)} \Big\rangle=-\theta(\tau)<{\hat{A}(\tau)\hat{A}^\dagger}>\mp\theta(-\tau)<\hat{A}^\dagger\hat{A}(\tau)> $$

Where $\tau$ is imaginary time. Temperature Green functions are (a)periodic in $\beta$, so the Fourier transform takes the following form:

$$G_{\hat{A}}(i\tilde{\omega}_n)=\frac{1}{\beta}\int_{0}^{\beta} d\tau e^{i\tilde{\omega}_n\tau}G_{\hat{A}}(\tau)$$

Where $i\tilde{\omega}_n$ is a Matsubara frequency. Doing this FT is not too hard since the second term is just zero given the above range of integration.

**This is what I want to make sure of:** when trying to Fourier transform $G_{\hat{A}}(-\tau)$, I just keep the second term and send the exponent to: $-i\tilde{\omega}_n\tau$. I am not sure if this step holds since the temperature Green functions are only related to one another on distinct time intervals (like on $(-\beta,0)$ instead), so would I have to perform an additional substitution past what I did to the exponent? Change the bounds of integration and maybe pick up a sign for Fermions? Will I run into trouble here if I try performing this temperature FT as I would usually do a FT in regular time?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question statement - in imaginary time, $G(\tau)$ must be a periodic function of $\tau$ with period $\beta$, or else the Matsubara decomposition is nonsense. What do you mean by "the temperature Green functions are only related to one another on distinct time intervals (like on (−,0) instead)" ?

Comment: Sure I can try and explain what I was saying, but first it turns out I had it right all along, no real subtly associated with the FT above. I just had to write the result in a different way to see it was right. Still, if you look at the lesser/greater Green functions, due to the periodic BCs, the Green functions on different intervals are related up to a multiple of $e^{-\mu \beta}$ (or something like this). I was just trying to come up with a reason my result was not right, but turns out it was!